# Smart disk error?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space, smart, bad-sectors, diagnostic

I performed disk tests with DLGDIAG and HDAT2 and none found bad sectors, but there is a !Smart error flag in HDAT2,

What does this mean?

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I would guess that is has to do with S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology; often written as SMART).  A quick web search will give you more information on SMART.

Comment: Doesn't the WinDlg/DlgDiag have window pane that lists more information about the smart status? Like, a status code number or something that you can google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smart error suggested allocation errors, which means bad sectors.

I had to backup all my data, the disk is still usable but in a precarious state.

[image]